# Capitalize first and third letter in names like McArthur or McMinn

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, html

Is there a way to identify compound names and correctly capitalize First and Third character?

While changing case is a trivial task using CSS, when dealing with compound names, I havent found any straight forward solution.

One thing that comes to mind is a use of some sort of look-up to identify names such as LeBare, or McDonalds, McArthur etc and then apply some logic to change the case ... anyone aware of any other viable solutions that might be out there so I wont have to reinvent the wheel (so to speak)?

Note: Users will be entering these names directly in a text box. There is no guarantee that a user will not enter something like mcMinn or macArthur etc. Having said that, I am also noticing names with "Le" and "La" prefixes (these are the names that have latin/spanish roots perhaps, I could be wrong though).

Comment: Have you asked Google?

Comment: Yes I have and no google did not have an answer for me. Thanks for checking though.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember during this process is that you could also have the case of "MacArthur" where it would be the 1st and 4th character. Depending on where you pull your data from (user input, database, etc.) I would say using it as is could be an option. However, if the name comes in as all lower case then you may have to compile a list of known name prefixes and check against it. My point is, unless the names come in as all lower case and will be displayed to a user I would just use the original formatting.

Comment: And even prefixes would be tricky since "Mack" should not be "MacK" and "Mackay" will only sometimes be "MacKay".

Comment: Good point! Wonder if someone has already compiled a list of these known compound names.

Comment: Users will be entering these names directly in a text box. There is no guarantee that a user will not enter something like mcMinn or macArthur etc.

Comment: @Robert Then use whatever the users actually gave you. They probably have a better idea than you do about how to properly write their name.

Comment: @IvanG: I wouldn't be too sure about that ... sometimes users can surprise you :)

Comment: @Robert: No doubt users can make things pretty complicated, but I suppose the GIGO principle comes into play here; if the user gives you garbage, give them that same garbage right back. It may even be beneficial to put a tooltip or label next to the box saying something about correct formatting. I am fairly certain though that you can always capitalize the first letter of the name so maybe stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it only with CSS. There are several "lettering" jQuery plug-in such as http://letteringjs.com/. You can put your own logic based on names in jQuery and style each letter with lettering library like

```
.target.char1, .target.char3 {
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use like this by Jquery.

```
$("#LastName").keyup(function () {
var last_name = $("#LastName").val();
var op = last_name.substr(0, 2);
if (op == "mc" || op == "Mc" || op == "MC") {
    $("#LastName").val("Mc" + (last_name.charAt(2).toUpperCase()) + last_name.substr(3).toLowerCase());
} else {
    $("#LastName").val(last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + last_name.substr(1).toLowerCase());
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through using index in javascript:

```js
var inputValue = "mcminn";

var transformedInput = '';

if(inputValue){
    for(var i=0; i<inputValue.length; i++){
    if(i===0 || i=== 2){
        transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
        } else {
            transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    }
  }
}

console.log(transformedInput);
```